# (Time.now.utc.to_date + 1.month + 15.days) != (Time.now.utc.to_date + 15.days + 1.month)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How's this possible?

```rb
Time.now.utc.to_date + 1.month + 15.days #=> Mon, 01 Dec 2014
Time.now.utc.to_date + 15.days + 1.month #=> Sun, 30 Nov 2014
```

Has anyone seen it?

/edit

I guess I asked the question a wrong way. How do you guys explain this then?

```rb
Time.now.utc.to_date + (15.days + 1.month) #=> Mon, 08 Dec 2014
Time.now.utc.to_date + (1.month + 15.days) #=> Tue, 09 Dec 2014

(15.days + 1.month) #=> 3888000
(1.month + 15.days) #=> 3888000
```

Comment: (A) Start from the origin, facing north. Turn 90 degrees, and then go front 100 m. (B) Start from the origin, facing north. Go front 100 m, and then turn 90 degrees. How is it possible that you get different results? Not everything in this world is commutative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let see [Integer#month](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/time.rb#L35), it returns an instance of `ActiveSupport::Duration`. At the rails console:

```
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > elapsed = 1.month
=> 2592000
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > elapsed.value
=> 2592000
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > elapsed.parts
=> [[:months,1]]
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > elapsed.is_a? ActiveSupport::Duration
=> true
```

It's time for the method: [ActiveSupport::Duration#+](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L19)

```
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > sum1 = 1.month + 15.days
=> 3888000
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > sum2 = 15.days + 1.month
=> 3888000
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > sum1.value
=> 3888000
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > sum1.parts
=> [[:months,1],[:days,15]]
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > sum2.value
=> 3888000
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > sum2.parts
=> [[:days,15],[:months,1]]
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > sum1 == sum2
=> true
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > sum1.value == sum2.value
=> true
~/rails/rfinan (1296000):1 > sum1.parts == sum2.parts
=> false
```

Now [Date#+](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb#L88-L96), the ActiveSupport version.

```
def plus_with_duration(other) #:nodoc:
  if ActiveSupport::Duration === other
    other.since(self)
  else
    plus_without_duration(other)
  end
end
alias_method :plus_without_duration, :+
alias_method :+, :plus_with_duration
```

That means: if I send :+ to a Date instance with a ActiveSupport::Duration instance as parameter, it calls [ActiveSupport::Duration#since](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L64), and the last one calls [ActiveSupport::Duration#sum](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L90), that injects over the date instance, and calls [Date#advance](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb#L110) on each of the parts of duration instance:

```
  def sum(sign, time = ::Time.current) #:nodoc:
    parts.inject(time) do |t,(type,number)|
      if t.acts_like?(:time) || t.acts_like?(:date)
        if type == :seconds
          t.since(sign * number)
        else
          t.advance(type => sign * number)
        end
      else
        raise ::ArgumentError, "expected a time or date, got #{time.inspect}"
      end
    end
  end
```

Remmember sum1.parts != sum2.parts?, sum send advance to the date instance orderly. Let see what means [Date#advance](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb#L110-L118)

```
def advance(options)
  options = options.dup
  d = self
  d = d >> options.delete(:years) * 12 if options[:years]
  d = d >> options.delete(:months)     if options[:months]
  d = d +  options.delete(:weeks) * 7  if options[:weeks]
  d = d +  options.delete(:days)       if options[:days]
  d
end
```

When advance recive `month: 1` it calls [Date#>>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E) from stdlib, that work diferently of ActiveSupport::Duration#+. At irb:

```
~ (main) > Date.new(2014,10,31) >> 1
=> #<Date: 2014-11-30 ((2456992j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
~ (main) > Date.new(2014,10,31) >> 2
=> #<Date: 2014-12-31 ((2457023j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
~ (main) > Date.new(2014,10,31) >> 3
=> #<Date: 2015-01-31 ((2457054j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
~ (main) > Date.new(2014,10,31) >> 4
=> #<Date: 2015-02-28 ((2457082j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
~ (main) > Date.new(2014,10,31) >> 5
=> #<Date: 2015-03-31 ((2457113j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
~ (main) > Date.new(2014,10,31) >> 12
=> #<Date: 2015-10-31 ((2457327j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
~ (main) > Date.new(2014,10,31) >> 1200
=> #<Date: 2114-10-31 ((2493486j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
~ (main) > Date.new(2014,10,31) >> 12000
=> #<Date: 3014-10-31 ((2822204j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

It's clear that Date#>> don't add days, add months and keep the day number. if the day isn't valid for the target month, it fixes it. Adding a fix number of months doesn't fixes the number of days added, because depend on the start date.

Now we can say that Date#+ is not the same of ActiveSupport::Duration#+, and we know why.

The anwer is Date#+ called with an ActiveSupport::Duration instance (say duration) doesn't care about duration.value, it uses duration.parts, which are different in each case.

Comment: `ActiveSupport::Duration#parts` was the key here. I thought that duration is simply a number of seconds. Thanks a lot!:)

Answer (score 5):

October has 31 days, November does not. This means that it depends a little on how you calculate the 31st + 1 Month.

For the first example:

- Now + 1 Month = 16-Nov
- 16-Nov + 15 days = 1-Dec

For the second example:

- Now + 15 days = 31-Oct
- 31-Oct + 1 Month = 30-Nov

Answer (score 4):

October has 31 days. When you add 15 days to Oct 16 you get Oct 31. Adding a month carries you to the same date on the next month - Nov. 31, but there is no Nov. 31 so it takes you to Nov 30.

If instead you add the month first, that carries you to Nov 16. Then adding 15 days carries you to Dec 01.

Comment: Great name to have when responding to Calendar-related questions (Julian Calendar)

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
(15.days + 1.month) #=> 3888000
(1.month + 15.days) #=> 3888000
```

You are not operating dates, you are operating seconds (Rails `Numeric < Object`). To prove, let's convert it back to days:

```
> 3888000 / 60 / 60 / 24
 => 45
```

45 = 30 + 15. So we know that, when operating seconds, or days, the compiler interprets `1.month` as 30 days by default when operating Numerics. See numerics reference:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-seconds

As you can see in the link above, when you operate Dates with Numerics, rails calls the `advance(options)` method which is responsible for executing correct Date operations. See advance definition on github:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ffc273577a795bb41068bfc2a1bb575ec51a9712/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb#L99

Also, when operating dates using `Time.now.utc.to_date + (1.month + 15.days)` the `+ ()` function will actually call the `advance(options)` method like this:

```
(Time.now.utc.to_date.advance(month:1)).advance(days:15) #fistCase
```

when you use `Time.now.utc.to_date + (15.days + 1.month)`, what will be called is this:

```
(Time.now.utc.to_date.advance(days:15)).advance(month:1) #secondCase
```

So, lets test #firstCase:

```
oct16 = Date.new(2014, 10, 16)
 > oct16 + (1.month + 15.days)
 => Mon, 01 Dec 2014
 > (oct16.advance(months:1)).advance(days:15)
 => Mon, 01 Dec 2014
```

The #firstCase conclusion is, it calls advance(month:1) resulting Nov-16, then it calls .advance(days:15) on Nov-16 and goes to Dez-01

Let's check the #secondCase:

```
> oct16 + (15.days + 1.month)
 => Sun, 30 Nov 2014
> (oct16.advance(days:15)).advance(months:1)
 => Sun, 30 Nov 2014
```

The #secondCase conclusion is, it calls advance(days:15), which results in Oct-31, than it calls advance(months: 1) on the last result, which would give us Nov-31, but wait! Nov-31 does not exist! So the interpreter is smart enough to understand that, since you were on the last day of the month(Oct-31), when you add 1.month, or advance(months:1), you are asking him to take you to the last day of the next month, in that case Nov-30.

That's the convention.